# C++ деструктор вызывается дважды

Tags: c++

Код класса:

```
class demo_
{
    protected:
        sf::CircleShape* demo_point;

    public:
        demo_()
        {
            std::cout << "init\n";
            demo_point = new sf::CircleShape();
        }

        ~demo_()
        {
            std::cout << "delete\n";
            delete demo_point;
        }
};
```

Код в main:

```
std::vector <demo_> obj;

    std::cout << "1\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        std::cout << "3\n";
        demo_ tpoint = demo_();
        //tpoint.SetColor(GetRandomColor());
        //tpoint.SetRadius(5.f);
        //tpoint.SetStartPosition((float)(rand() % sizeWindowX), (float)(rand() %  sizeWindowY));
        obj.push_back(tpoint);
    }
    std::cout << "2\n";
```

Результат работы:

```
1
3
init
delete
3
init
delete
delete
```

Исключение : нарушение прав доступа при чтении по адресу

Почему деструктор вызвался дважды для второго demo_ в цикле?

Comment: "Чего в этом супе не хватает?"

Comment: у вас есть demo_ tpoint = demo_().  Обе объекта содержат указатели, указывающие на один и тот же объект, и деструктор  и того и другого объекта освобождает один и тот же участок памяти(см. ответ ниже(выше)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Краткий ответ - здесь нарушение правила [трех/пяти](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D1%82%D1%80%D1%91%D1%85_(C%2B%2B))

Так как у Вас нетривиальный конструктор и деструктор (а по простому - в классе есть голый указатель), то нужно дописать конструктор копирования и оператор присваивания с правильным пробросом/копированием указателя. И все будет работать.

Почему возникла проблема? когда вектор внутри расширяется, он выделяет новое место и копирует туда свои элементы. А конструктора копирования нет - поэтому он сгенерировал его сам, где просто копирует сам указатель. А когда деструктор освобождает, то у другого деструктора возникают проблемы.

Так как один конструктор Вы не учли, то Вам и не понятно, почему ещё раз вызывается деструктор.

Comment: Все понел, спасибо